# Compiling to older versions of Java using Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have my code written in Java 17. I was wondering if there is a way to compile to older Java versions (8 and onwards).

Many folks online suggest that I should use something like this:

```xml
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

However, when I do that, I get the following issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: warning: source release 17 requires target release 17
```

Using `release` with *maven-compiler-plugin* instead did not help either.

What I don't understand is that if the target and source need to be exactly the same, then why do we event need both?

I am using Maven 3.8.3, by the way.

Comment: Simple answer to this. It's not possible. This is based on using JDK17 features (sealed classes, text blocks, var etc.) which do not exist in JDK8...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expectations of the JDK are wrong with regards to compiler compatibility. The compiler is not forward compatible, it is backwards compatible. Therefore, in your case, setting the compiler `target` to **Java 1.8** with `source` at **Java 17** will not work.

There are new features in **Java 17** which are not compatible with **Java 1.8** and therefore **Java JDK 1.8** will not understand what they are and will definitely throw **Syntax Errors**. That explains the warning you are getting from the Maven Compiler plugin.

At the same time, **Java 17** is too far ahead. While it will understand all the syntax present in previous versions of Java, you will encounter compile time errors due to missing classes. An example of such an error is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` or `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` as some classes have been deprecated and removed.

Starting with **Java 9**, Java decided to only support a maximum of three versions back. Therefore if your are working with **Java 17** the last support would be **Java 14**. In this case, if you write all code compatible with **JDK 14** and compile with **JDK 17**, it would continue to work for all versions in between.

This is similar to how it has always been with **Java 1.8** and below. The code has to be compatible with your target environment. So, if your `targetCompatibility` is **Java 1.8**, then your `sourceCompatibility` should also be **Java 1.8** and below.

An example:

```xml
<!-- Correct -->
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<!-- Wrong -->
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I really had them mixed in my head. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: I found a mention of the "one + three back" policy of supported source and target options in this draft (not finalized) [*JEP 182: Policy for Retiring javac -source and -target Options*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/182). But I could not find any official policy statement. Can you cite a reference, for the record? (Also, very good Answer.)

Comment: If you like to compile you source into JDK8 you have to use `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>` (JDK9+) instead of source/target etc... that will keep the created class file compatible with JDk8... That's the easiest way to do that...

Comment: @khmarbaise I mentioned in the question that `release` did not work

Comment: @MansurGulami It works... If you write your code with only JDK8 features it will work.. The problem is that you seemed to misunderstand the compatibility because if you use language features of JDK9+ then it will not work because they can't be translated to JDK8...so if you use JDK8 features only the `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>` will work...Do not use `source` and `target` use release only...Apart from that you should use `8` instead of `1.8`...because the version is `8` instead of `1.8` from JDK9+...Also please check to be use most recent versions of compiler-plugin.

Comment: @khmarbaise well it won't matter in that case because what I wanted was to write code in Java 17 and be able to compile it to an older version which thanks to you all I found out that I misunderstood the backward/forward compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *always* the case that you can't compile with downwards compatibility. However, just as 1.8 introduced lambdas, which couldn't be made compatible with pre-1.8 runtimes, 17 includes new features (particularly sealed classes) that older runtimes can't understand. If you want to tell the compiler "I won't use those features, so you can be compatible", you set your compiler release to an older version.

Comment: But shouldn't it throw some sort of exception saying "I don't know what this is"? The error I shared just says they need to be the same, and that's the root cause of the exception I am getting

Comment: @MansurGulami No, it says that _source release 17 specifically_ is not downwards compatible and that you need to change one or the other.

Comment: I actually tried different combinations as well. For example, source: 11, target 8 also gives me the exact same error. I feel like in Maven both of those things need to be the same.

Comment: @MansurGulami simply not correct.